# Supress warning from gcc init_priority attribute

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, warnings

G++ is giving me warnings about init_priority attribute:

```
g++ -c -o src/core/ModuleManager.o -Wall -fPIC -imacros ./src/configs/config.hpp -O2 -I./src/include  src/core/ModuleManager.cpp
src/core/ModuleManager.cpp:27:29: warning: requested init_priority is reserved for internal use
```

Is there a way to supress this specific warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to supress this specific warning?

Yes: don't use init_priority reserved for internal use (priority <= 100).

There is a *reason* it is reserved, and if you ignore the warning, you'll eventually have to debug a problem you will have hard time understanding.

Never lie to your compiler -- it will get you!

Comment: Right... I thought the init_priority attribute itself is reserved, not specific priority values... I better RDFM next time I guess...