# init_seg and warning C4073 from library code?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, warnings

We have a C++ library. It has four static objects that are sensitive to initialization order (two of them are strings from the standard library).

We are using [`init_seg(lib)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977wcck.aspx) to control the order of initialization of C++ static objects in the library. The source file that is using it is compiled and used in either a dynamic link library or static library. According to the documentation for `init_seg`:

> ... It is particularly important to use the init_seg pragma in ***dynamic-link libraries (DLLs) or libraries*** requiring initialization. (emphasis mine)

The Visual Studio solution is organized into four projects. One is the static library, or is the dynamic library, one is the test driver for the static library, and one is the test driver for the dynamic library.

Under Visual Studio, compiling the source file with the `init_seg` results in [warning C4073](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5c0a6es.aspx), with the text *initializers put in library initialization area*. According to MSDN:

> Only third-party library developers should use the library initialization area, which is specified by #pragma init_seg. The following sample generates C4073...

The code using the `init_seg` is used in the libraries only, and ***not*** used with the test drivers. I've verified the static library and dynamic library project settings, and they are clearly calling out library artifacts.

Why am I receiving the C4073 warning?

Comment: you could disable the warning `#  pragma warning (disable:4073)`

Answer (score 2):

It's just warning you, not even a wag of the finger, it's more like "are you sure?"  When you use a 3rd party library that uses this feature it warned its developer too - unless he turned it off with `#pragma warning`.  You could do the same.  Or you could use segment `user` not segment `lib`: your strings will still be constructed before *your* application code runs.  Segment `lib` is really intended for things like ... oh, Qt or MFC or a framework like that that needs to be initialized before *any* application code runs, including your early initialization stuff in `user`.

Here's some more information:

Suppose you have a library for your own app.  And it has some stuff that needs to be initialized before any of its code is run, because certain classes exposed by this library are intended to be (or, are allowed to be) statically allocated in your application code, and those classes do complicated stuff in their constructors that needs, say, some large bollix of precomputed (but not static) data.  So for that precomputed stuff you precompute it in the constructor of a class (a different class) and you statically allocate an instance of that class, so that the initialization of that instance calls its constructor which precomputes all that stuff, and that static instance you mark with `pragma init_seg(user)`.  Now, before any of your application code runs - including any constructors of static instances of this library's class in your code - the library's `init_seg(user)` code will all run, and so, by the time your static instances of this library's classes get constructed the data they need will be there.

Now consider stuff that really has got to be there early, of which static instances exist that you can call.  E.g., `std::cout`.  You can call methods on `std::cout` in constructors of your own classes that you have static instances of.  Obviously, the object `std::cout` needs to be initialized before any of your code runs.  And some of your code might run in stuff you've marked `init_seg(user)`.  So Microsoft places all such code - that is, the constructors for `std::cout` etc. - in `init_seg(compiler)`.  That stuff will run before *anything* else.

So what is `init_seg(lib)` for?  Well, suppose you're a framework like MFC.  You expose stuff like the Application object that the user will (is likely to, is expected to) create a static instance of.  Some of the code in Application which will be run at static initialization time depends on other stuff in MFC that needs to be initialized.  So obviously it needs to be `init_seg`ged, but where?  `compiler` is for the compiler and runtimes alone, and your framework stuff (MFC) might be used in the `init_seg(user)` that the user is allowed to use ... so you get an intermediate level between `compiler` and `user` - that's `lib`.

Now it is fairly rare to need anything like that because most C++ libraries used by programs are not themselves used by multiple libraries and thus don't need to make sure they're initialized before all other "ordinary" libraries.  MFC does, because you might have bought 3rd party MFC control or other libraries from one or more vendors, and those depend on MFC, and those might use MFC things in their constructors, and you might use objects from those libraries statically, so MFC needs to be initialized before those other libraries.

But in most cases, *your* library isn't going to be a dependency of *other* C++ libraries that people are using.  Thus there isn't any kind of dependency chain where your library needs to be initialized before other libraries.  Your libraries might need to be initialized before your user code, yes, but there isn't any order in which they need to be initialized.  So `init_seg(user)` is fine for all of them.

And, Microsoft (and generally, most C++ experts) will tell you:  If there *is* some kind of order dependency in which your separate libraries need to be initialized *at the time of static initialization of your app* then you're doing it wrong.  Seriously.  There's a design problem there.

So, to respond to a comment:  It isn't a compiler bug.  It's a user warning.  Fairly benign:  Nothing's going to go wrong if you ignore it (unlike, say ignoring a warning about casting from long to int).  But if you're using `init_seg(lib)` you might not really be understanding what that compiler feature is all about, so they'd like you to think about it.  And after you've thought about it, if you still want to do it, go ahead and turn the warning off.

Comment: OK, so I'm clear: it sounds like you are telling me this is a compiler bug. That is, I'm receiving it for no apparent reason. Is that correct? (And this library has the same requirements as Qt or MFC - we need to ensure particular code runs *in case* the use code has static objects that depend on it).

Comment: @jww: I expanded my answer significantly.  Does it answer your questions now?

Comment: My question was, *Why am I receiving the C4073 warning*. You have not answered that question. I don't need the analysis. I already know we need to tend to the order of initialization for the static C++ objects. (I can take you through the details of why/how we know, but it does not really matter for the question. But the short answer is: Valgrind told us when we were using uninitialized values, and it traced back to the order the C++ objects were being created).

Comment: You're getting the warning because you're using the feature.

Comment: So I'm clear: you're telling me that using this feature as intended produces a warning, and its by design. Is that correct? I have to ask because its not obvious to me why the warning is being emitted for ***correct*** use of the feature (as opposed to *incorrect* use of the feature).

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  This is a non-standard bit of C++ that was invented by Microsoft to solve a problem with MFC:  They had this framework where people would use static instances of classes exposed by it in their *libraries*, MFC had to be initialized before all other libraries.  That's all it was for.  But for various reasons it had to be documented, and when documented other people would naturally use it, and Microsoft didn't want to start a "priority" war where everyone's library was marked init_seg(library) so it could be initialized first. They want you to use init_seg(user).

Comment: *"This is a non-standard bit of C++ that was invented by Microsoft to solve a problem with MFC..."* - no, that's not necessarily true. The order of initialization of C++ objects across translation units is not specified by the C++ standard. See, for example, [Order of Initialization Fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html) on  the C++ FAQ. GCC provides [`init_priority`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html) for the same problem (and its just as non-standard).

Comment: Yes, it is non standard.  Did GCC have it first, or VC++?  Don't know and don't care.  BTW, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564368/supress-warning-from-gcc-init-priority-attribute) you see that GCC's warning can't be suppressed either if you try to use their version of "library", a priority <= 100.

Comment: @Daivd - Sorry; I was commenting on the problem being created by Microsoft and MFC. But you are right - the C++ committee has ***never*** addressed the problem, so I consider it a defect in the C++ language. GCC's `init_priority` does not use `compiler`, `user` and `lib`, so its comparing apples to oranges. If one follows the manual, then there will be no warning under GCC. Which loops me back to the reason for my question: I followed the Microsoft manual, did as I was told, and yet I still got the warning.

Comment: @jww Your question was reasonable, perhaps the answer isn't what you expected. But there it is. I myself have a lot of quarrels with the designers of VC++ w.r.t. the existence of certain warning messages.  Also with the designers of gcc, clang, C#, sun/oracle java, eclipse java, and ghc, to name just the most prominent compilers I use. Oh well.